# network not available in container created with podman run with non-default network

Tags: podman

I am following a tutorial meant for Docker. I created a network using:

```
sudo podman network create --subnet 10.1.0.0/16 --gateway 10.1.0.1 \
--ip-range=10.1.4.0/24 --driver=bridge br04
```

Then, created and ran a container using:

```
podman container run --name network-test01 -it --network br04 centos /bin/bash
```

`ip a` ran inside the container returns only the loopback interface.

Why is my network not available in the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `podman` with `sudo` to connect to network:

`sudo podman container run --name network-test01 -it --network br04 centos /bin/bash`